# post call is not working in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to perform a post call in node js, i am testing it through post but i am not able to retrive data,
my node code,

```
 exports.login = function( req, res ) {
 console.log("Params:"+req.body.email);
  //console.log('email:'+params.email);
 connection.query('SELECT * FROM profile where email ='+req.body.email,function(error,result,rows,fields){
    if(!!error){console.log(error)
      console.log('fail');
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  // }

  });}
```

my routes,

```
 router.post('/login',cors(), admin.login);
```

i am getting fail and my error is

```
{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1]
```

my input through postman

```
{"email":"s@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Looks like your query is not getting the parameter in where clause, first thing i would do is check what function is returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build the query string directly, this leaves you open to injection attacks and also chokes on certain characters, as you are experiencing here. Use a placeholder like so:

```
var query = "select * from profile where email = ?";

connection.query(query, [req.body.email], function(error,result,rows,fields) {
...
```

Comment: Its working now but i am getting an empty array [] even if i had data

Comment: How can i write a command like this "select * from profile where email = s@gmail.com and pasword = 1"

Comment: var query = 'select * from profile where email = ? and password = ?';
 connection.query(query,req.body.email,req.body.password,function(error,result,rows,fields){

Comment: Use an array for multiple parameters, connection.query(query, [req.body.email,req.body.password], func‌​tion(error,result,ro‌​ws,fields)